# Sorting pandas dataframe by column index instead of column name

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Given this sample dataframe named `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Mary', 'Joe', 'Jessie'], 'score': [10, 3, 13]})


name     score
Mary     10
Joe      3
Jessie   13
```

Now trying to sort the dataframe instead of by column, by the column via its location:

Typical way to sort dataframe:

```
df = df.sort_values['score']
```

Trying to sort it like this (which is not working):

```
df = df.sort_values[df.iloc[:, 1]]
```

This raises an otherwise unintelligible "Key Error" with no explanation what it is referring to.

I need to do this because the function containing this code will have a different name for the second column each time it runs so I cannot hard code a column name for sorting and instead need to sort by whatever the second column is, no matter its name.

Thanks for taking a moment to check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_values` is not an indexer but a method. You use it with `[]` instead of `()` but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

If you want to sort your dataframe by the second column whatever the name, use:

```
>>> df.sort_values(df.columns[1])
     name  score
1     Joe      3
0    Mary     10
2  Jessie     13
```